# Can I override v-model auto select with an option :selected property?

Tags: vue.js

I would like the :selected property on the option to override the v-model property on the select tag but I'm not sure how to make it have priority.  I need the v-model so it can sync with the store.

```
<select 
  v-model="device.current_schedule_settings[0]"
  @change="$v.device.channels.$touch()"
  @blur="$v.device.channels.$touch()"
>
  <option v-for="value in relativeInput" :key="value[0]" :value="value[0]" :selected="value[0] == rounded(device.current_schedule_settings[0])">
    {{ value[0] }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, v-model needed to be split up into 2 sections

```
v-bind:value="rounded(device.current_schedule_settings[0])"
@input="device.current_schedule_settings[0] = $event.target.value"
```